# Project structure for react native including native iOS,Android?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, terminal, setup-project

I am trying to get my hands on react native and I'm confused at this point that how we can create a structure something like this

```
MainProject-Folder
|
|iOS-Native-Project-Folder
|
|Android-Native-Project-Folder
|
|Shared-React-Native-Project-Folder/Files-For-Both (iOS/Android)
```

I've googled but didn't find any article/blog post explaining this kind of structure.
I just want to create a basic structure in which I can have few screens shared code between android/iOS, And at some places I want to have native objective-C/Swift/Java code for iOS/Android.

If someone can guide me in right direction it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

if you have created your project using

```
react-native init projectName
```

then you will get iOS and android native directories

just add one more folder as src and keep all the shared code there.

refer the image attached which depicts the same :)[image]